# Cron Command for twice a month on Sat @12am

Tags: cron, cronjob

I am wondering if someone can help with the simple but sometimes confusing commands regarding Cron jobs.

I would like a cron job to run twice a month on a Saturdat @12am.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is unfortunately not possible. The schedule “twice a month on saturdays” cannot be expressed using *crontab*. You can say “twice a month” and you can say “on saturdays” but you cannot link these conditions using AND. They will always be linked using OR. As per `man 5 crontab`:

> Note: The day of a command's execution can be specified by two fields --
> day of month, and day of week.  If both fields are restricted (ie, are
> not *), the command will be run when either field matches the current
> time.  For example, ``30 4 1,15 * 5'' would cause a command to be run at
> 4:30 am on the 1st and 15th of each month, plus every Friday.

However, you can use a shell expression to help!

I found [this suggestion](https://cron.help/every-2-weeks-on-sunday) on a website:

```
0 0 * * Sun [ $(expr $(date +%W) % 2) -eq 1 ] && /path/to/command
```

Let‘s disect it!

- `0 0 * * Sun` is the cron schedule. It runs at midnight every sunday.
- `[ $(expr $(date +%W) % 2) -eq 1 ] && /path/to/command` is the command (as far as cron is concerned)

  - `[ $(expr $(date +%W) % 2) -eq 1 ]` successfully returns if the week number of the year is odd

    - `expr $(date +%W) % 2` takes the output of `date +%W` (“week number of year, with Monday as first day of week (00..53)”, other variations are also available) and applies a modulo operation (divide by two, return the remainder)
    - `[ $something -eq 1 ]` tests whether `$something` equals 1 and returns the result as its exit code
  - `&& /path/to/command` means to run the command if the previous command was successful (ie. if the week number is odd)

Using this expression, you can keep your scripts unmodified and the decision logic inside the *crontab* file.

Answer (score -1):

According to the **man 5 crontab**

> Step values can be used in conjunction with ranges.  Following a range with **/<number>**  specifies  skips  of  the  number's  value through  the range.  For example, **0-23/2** can be used in the hours field to specify command execution every other hour (the alternative in the V7 standard is **0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22**).  Steps are also permitted after an asterisk, so if you want to  say **every two hours**, just use ***/2**.

---

It's `0 0 * */2 6 <other parts>`

Comment: With that entry, the command will be executed every two days each month plus every Saturday.

Answer (score -1):

I think

0 0 * */2 6

will run every other month, each saturday of that month.

In order to be twice a month it has to be

0 0 */15 * 6

Cheers!

Comment: This won't work as expected. The day columns are linked by OR. This means the command will run _every_ saturday _and_ on the 15th and on the 30th of a month.